# partial string matching in sql

Tags: sql

I need to match two columns from two different tables based on the number of string they have in common. so for instance in column one I have:

```
================Table 1==============================
ID     desc             Year      Month
123    food_drink       2016      8
345    shoe_bag         2016      8
678    001_toilet_paper 2015      7
910    Bags_of_thing    2015      6

======================table 2======================
ID      Name           Year        month
ad      drink_server   2016        8 
ac      shoe_shiny     2016        8
aa      white_paper    2015        7
cc      blue_bags      2015        6
```

Is there a way to combine the two tables by joining on year, month and similar string in the description and name. So comparing the desc and name column to see if they have >= 5 strings in common, then:

```
===================================================
ID1  ID2  name          desc              Year  Month
123  ad   drink server  food_drink        2016   8
678  aa   white_paper   001_toilet_paper  2016   7
```

In essence, I need a way to compare the number of common strings between two columns of different tables. Thanks.

Comment: you can write any `join` you want - join clauses simply boil down to a boolean true/false: true = join the records, false = no join. but your substring matches are NOT going to be pretty. sql is not a good language to be doing arbitrary string manipulation in. you'd be FAR better off normalizing the tables and putting those food/drink/server/blah/blah keywords into their own child table, and then matching will be a trivial join + equality test.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. You would like to compare each row from table1 with every row from table2 to check if they have at lease (or exactly) 5 common fields or you want to compare column with column?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: microsoft server management studio

Comment: Hi. I'm afraid the question is not clear. Can you lead us by example? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your issue boils down to the fact that your data is not even in First Normal Form, making it very difficult to deal with it in SQL.

This is what I would do:

- Create a temporary table that splits the fields into words. I presume the ID is the key in both tables. The tables would look like:

  ================Table  words1==============================

  ```
  ID1     word
  123    food
  123    drink
  345    shoe
  345    bag
  ...
  ```

=============table words2 ======================

```
    ID2      word
    ad      drink
    ad      server 
    ac      shoe
    ac      shiny
    ...
```

Now you can easily find the IDs that have 5 words or more in common:

```
SELECT ID1, ID2 FROM words1 JOIN words2 ON (word1.word = words2.word) 
GROUP by ID1, ID2
having count(*) >= 5;
```

Once you have the ID1 and ID2 you can join back to the original tables and retrieve the rest of the data you want.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who answered. I ended up using R to string match using on of the techniques described in the link below:

https://www.r-bloggers.com/fuzzy-string-matching-a-survival-skill-to-tackle-unstructured-information/